# Only show non-repeated characters in a column in a new column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a df with strings such as ABABAB, i would like to create a new column  in such df that would bring just non-repeated characters of such strings, in the example above, just AB.

I have tried ''.join() but this does not work well with I get an error message saying that a string was expected.

Illustrative desired outcome:

```
  Column_1     Column_2
   ABABAB         AB
   KGKGKG         KG
   ACACAC         AC
   PCTPCTPCT      PCT
```

Please keep in mind there are situations in which the unique characters are more than just two

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified. Show the errormessage and exact stacktrace as well as enough code to reproduce it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799036/python-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-character-from-string enjoy

Comment: This is not a trivial problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256655/finding-repetitions-in-a-string

Comment: Is the order of the letters important? `PCTPCTPCT` --> `CTP` or `TPC` or `PCT`

Comment: Are duplicates important?  `ABBABBABB` -> `AB` or `ABB` ?

Comment: What about if no duplicate is in? `ABCDEFE` --> `ABCDEFE` or `ABCDEF` (in any order)

Comment: It would be preferable to keep the order. I am looking through the answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you want:

```
df["Column_2"] = df["Column_1"].apply(lambda x: "".join(set(list(x))))
df
    Column_1    Column_2
0   ABABAB  AB
1   KGKGKG  KG
2   ACACAC  AC
3   PCTPCTPCT   PTC
```

Comment: does not work for `'ABBABB'` also: does not guarantee to keep letters in order as sets are not sorted and might return ACP for PCAPCAPCA - will alsno not work for `'ABCDEFE'` which has no repeat

Comment: `'PCT'` are all repeated characters. They occure trice in `'PCTPCTPCT'`- what is looked for is the shortest "sequence" that does not repeat - and your code will remove duplicate letters from sequences - hence won't work for `'ABBABBABB'` which probably should return `'ABB'` but will give either `'AB'` or `'BA'`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order, you could use sets for this: they keep only unique items of an iterable (such as a string). Then join the set together to make it a string:

```
df['Column_1'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(set(x)))
#0    BA
#1    GK
#2    CA
#3    CTP
```

Comment: does not work for `'ABBABB'` also: does not guarantee to keep letters in order as sets are not sorted and might return ACP for PCAPCAPCA - will alsno not work for `'ABCDEFE'` which has no repeat

Comment: Could you clarify? It outputs `'AB'`, as expected, right?

Comment: It appears to me your comment changed after I responded to it. I already wrote in my answer that it only works if you don't care about the order (which he didn't specify should matter). He says he wants non-repeated characters, which I interpret as unique characters, which is in fact what this returns, right? @PatrickArtner

Comment: I asked for clarification. I read the question differently - until I get clarification I'll redact my dv